# How can I code 3-bit binary counter module based on state diagrams?

Tags: verilog, circuit

[image: 3bit counter state diagram]

I want to build a module based on this state diagram. The code below is the module I wrote and the test bench.When you build this, 
you can face this error.

./3bit_c_sdiagram.v:1: syntax error
I give up.

How can I solve this syntax error? and
If my code is far from the solution, how do I code it?

***3bit_c_sdiagram.v***

```
module 3bit_c_sdiagram(y_out, clock, reset);

output y_out;
input clock, reset;

reg[2:0]    state;
parameter S0=3'b000, S1=3'b001, S2=3'b010, S3=3'b011, S4=3'b100, S5=3'b101, 
S6=3'b110, S7=3'b111;

always @ (posedge clock, negedge reset)
 if(reset == 0) state <= S0;    //Initialize to state S0
 else case(state)
  S0:   if(clock) state <= S1; else state <= S0;
  S1:   if(clock) state <= S2; else state <= S1;
  S2:   if(clock) state <= S3; else state <= S2;
  S3:   if(clock) state <= S4; else state <= S3;
  S4:   if(clock) state <= S5; else state <= S4;
  S5:   if(clock) state <= S6; else state <= S5;
  S6:   if(clock) state <= S7; else state <= S6;
  S7:   if(clock) state <= S0; else state <= S7;
 endcase

 assign y_out = (state == S7);
endmodule
```

**simulat.v**

```
module simulate;
wire t_y_out;
reg t_reset;
reg t_clock;

3bit_c_sdiagram M1(t_y_out, t_clock, t_reset);

initial #200 $finish; 
initial begin

$dumpfile("test.vcd");
$dumpvars(0,simulate);

   t_reset = 0;
   t_clock = 0;
   #5 t_reset = 1;

 repeat(16)
   #5 t_clock = ~t_clock;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: +1 Because you made a test-bench, all assignment in the clocked section are non-blocking and you have a reset. I have seen designs **a lot worse** then this

Comment: How can I code it... ?

Comment: Gazua. The +1 means I have up-voted your question. It is meant as a complement for doing such a good job. Just get your module name sorted out and I think it will all work.

Answer (score 2):

`3bit_c_sdiagram` is an illegal *identifer* (ie name) in Verilog. Verilog names can contain letters, numbers, dollar signs or underscores, but **they must start with a letter or an underscore**.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other solution, your module name cannot start with a number.

I am adding this answer just to outline one thing in your example (even if it is not an answer to your question). In your code, you have:

```
always @ (posedge clock, negedge reset)
 if(reset == 0) state <= S0;    //Initialize to state S0
 else case(state)
  S0:   if(clock) state <= S1; else state <= S0;
```

This always@ statement will run in two cases:
- when your clock rises
- OR when your reset drops

You first test `reset==0`, then go into the `else` statement. Based on what was said before, that `else` statement will run ONLY when your clock rises (because you know reset != 0). 
Bottom line: no need to test for `if (clock)`. You can do the following:

```
always @ (posedge clock, negedge reset)
 if(reset == 0) state <= S0;    //Initialize to state S0
 else case(state)
  S0:   state <= S1; else state <= S0;
...
```

The `else state <= S0` statements are not needed either, this is what will happen by default (your reg will no change value unless you explicitly change it). But if it helps in clarifying things for you, it doesn't hurt either...

I hope this helps!